# Vagrant with local VMs

Tags: vagrant

I'm very new to the concept of Vagrant. I'm not too sure of why to use Vagrant when I can spin up VM's using VirtualBox.

However, because I'd like to learn new things, I'm trying to understand how to use Vagrant but I keep getting into issues.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Installed VirtualBox
2. Installed latest Vagrant 1.7.4
3. Vagrant init /desktop/vm  #This is where I wanted to have my Vagrantfile
4. In /usr/VirtualBox VMs/ I have two VMs. Win7IE9 and Win7IE11.

How do I carry on from here to use Vagrant and spin either of these VMs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

steps 1 and 2 are correct.

After, you need to understand vagrant works with [vagrant boxes](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/boxes.html) :

> Instead of building a virtual machine from scratch, which would be a
>   slow and tedious process, Vagrant uses a base image to quickly clone a
>   virtual machine. These base images are known as boxes in Vagrant, and
>   specifying the box to use for your Vagrant environment is always the
>   first step after creating a new Vagrantfile.

so for any VM that you want vagrant to spin up, you would need a base box. You can find on internet box for most of OS (any kind of linux, windows ...) and if needed you can create a box by yourself.

If you have existing VM that you would like vagrant to manage, you would need to create a vagrant box from the existing VM. You can do so by running [`vagrant package`](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/package.html)

> This packages a currently running VirtualBox environment into a re-usable box

You would run vagrant package for your 2 existing VM and add the box to vagrant, so vagrant will be able to create VMs from those box easily.

once box files are generated, you might need to run `vagrant box add <box name> <file.box>`

once you have box installed for vagrant, you can check by running `vagrant box list`

From there, you can run the `vagrant init <box name>` which will create the `Vagrantfile` (in the directory where you run the init command) based on the new box and you can run `vagrant up` from there to spin up a new VM based on your new box.

To create a VM for the second box, you would need to do the same from another directory.

Comment: Ok, starting to make more sense now :)
So when issuing 'vagrant up', how would vagrant know which VM to spin up?

Comment: adding some step for the initialization of `Vagrantfile`